# Licensing: Application Refund Time

Tags: android, android-lvl

Is there any way to ask (programmatically) GooglePlay if the application refund time has expired?

Edit: what i wanto to achive is that if users are inside the refund period I do want to skip the licensing check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Google does not expose such API to the developers.

If your purpose is to use 'Strict' licensing mode check within the refund period, then just do the check for the first 24 hours after the app is run for the first time. Yes, even though the official refund window is 15 minutes, a user can still request a refund within the 24 hours period.

So after 24 hours, if the user passes 'Strict' licensing mode check, then you can switch to a more relaxing mode, the ServerManagedPolicy or your own policy.

Comment: But do you need to keep track of the installation time?

Comment: Yes, otherwise how would you track the 24 hours period? When the app is run for the first time, you can store the time right then in your database or shared preference. I would obfuscate or encrypt it though.

Comment: db and sharedpreference will be delete if users  uninstall the application and files could be easly deleted. How store in a secure way?

Comment: When they uninstall and reinstall, wouldn't that count as a new 24 hours strict period? And if they requested refund after they uninstall and try to install it afterward, the LVL library will know that they don't have the license to run the app. This is of course assuming the phone is not rooted.